# Hamel basis dense in the unit sphere

Tags: vector-spaces, set-theory, banach-spaces, hamel-basis

I know that a Hamel basis can be dense in a Banach space (it was probably posted somewhere on this forum). I would like to construct a certain counter-example and doing this, I encountered the following problem (which might sound to be ad hoc).

> Let $X$ be a non-separable Banach space. Is it possible to find a Hamel basis for $X$ consisting of unit vectors which is dense in the unit sphere?

Or, maybe the other extreme can happen:

> Let $\lambda$ be a cardinal as big as you wish and let $X$ be a Banach space of cardinality $\lambda$. Suppose $A$ is contained in the unit sphere of $X$ and $|A|=\lambda$. Must $A$ be linearly dependent?

Comment: If $H$ is a Hamel basis of an infinite dimensional Banach space $B$, then $|H| \geq 2^{\aleph_0}$ (check) and hence $|B| = |H| 2^{\aleph_0} = |H|$. It follows that you can inductively construct a Hamel basis inside the unit sphere that meets each of its open set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second answer is obviously false, for large enough $\lambda$.

For $\lambda>\frak c$ note that the dimension of $X$ must be $\lambda$, therefore it has a basis of size $\lambda$.

Let $B$ be such basis, take $B'=\left\{\frac1{\|v\|}v\mid v\in B\right\}$, then $B'$ is a subset of the unit sphere, and it is a basis of $X$ and so linearly independent.

Comment: I'm afraid this set is linearly dependent.

Comment: Oops. I read "must it be linearly **independent**".

Comment: @usao: I edited my answer.